# Cannot loop Pivot Chart ShowAllFieldButtons on Multiple Sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have a scenario where I need to hide the Field Buttons on a Pivot Chart. I need to loop through a series of sheets, and do this to each chart on each sheet.

I know I'm missing something simple - but I'm having trouble looping it through.

```
Sub DivisionMacro()
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim ch As ChartObject
    
    'Create Division Sheets
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable12").ShowPages PageField:= _
                                                      "User Custom Fields.Division2023"
    
    'UnProtect Sheet
    Cells.Select
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect
    
    'Loop Through
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        'Hide Top Row
        ws.Rows(1).Hidden = True
        'Create Chart
        ws.Shapes.AddChart2(216, xlBarClustered).Select
        'Show Chart Field Buttons
        ws.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
        ActiveChart.ShowAllFieldButtons = False
        
        'Protect Sheet
        'ws.Protect Password:=strPassword, DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True, _
        'UserInterfaceOnly:=True, AllowFormattingCells:=False, AllowFormattingColumns:=True, _
        'AllowFormattingRows:=False, AllowInsertingColumns:=False, AllowInsertingRows:=False, _
        'AllowInsertingHyperlinks:=False, AllowDeletingColumns:=False, AllowDeletingRows:=False, _
        'AllowSorting:=False, AllowFiltering:=False, AllowUsingPivotTables:=True
        
    Next ws
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, there's no need to do any selecting or activating.  Secondly, when creating the chart, assign the object to a variable, and then use that variable to set your settings.  Here's an example...

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim shp As Shape

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    On Error Resume Next
    Set pt = ws.PivotTables(1)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Not pt Is Nothing Then
        Set shp = ws.Shapes.AddChart2(216, xlBarClustered)
        With shp.Chart
            .SetSourceData pt.TableRange2
            .ShowAllFieldButtons = False
        End With
        Set pt = Nothing
    End If
Next ws
```

Note that as it loops through each worksheet, it first checks whether a pivot table exists.  If so, then it proceeds to create the chart, etc.

Comment: Perfect. One follow up question - the chart has 2 series. How do i set the series colour?  I tried .SeriesCollection(2).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(51, 204, 51)

Comment: The syntax seems correct.  Did you you place that line of code within the `With shp.Chart / End With` statement?

Comment: Yeah I did but it still bugged out.

Comment: Ah I know what's happening - some of my charts only have 1 series. So it faults on series 2 cause it's not finding it.

Comment: Are you getting an error message?  If so, which one?  If you're get a parameter not valid error, then it's likely that the pivot chart does not contain  a series with the specified index.

Comment: I see that you've now have it solved, good. :-)

Comment: Yep that's the issue. Nearly all of my charts have 2 series, but a couple have one. hmm.. not sure I know how to write that. searching...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254700/discussion-between-campbell-and-domenic).

Comment: Just loop through each Series in the SeriesCollection for the chart to set the colour.